# How To hide only dragging element in scroll bar in browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I want to hide that red marked scrolling element, but scroll bar should be the there !

Comment: Your explanation is not enough

Comment: You want to hide the scrollbar but not the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
Css
.parent{
      position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;}
.child{
  height: 150px;   
   width: 318px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

apply css accordingly

Check it on following link
http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/c11khcak/3/